# Clojureの関数で渡されたものと同じ型のコレクションを返すには？

Tags: clojure

例えば次のような関数を定義したとして、渡されたコレクションと同じ型を返す良い方法はないでしょうか？
ただし、評価値の順序がおかしくならないようにお願いします。

```
(defn rotate [n coll]
  (let [at (if (neg? n) (Math/abs n) (- (count coll) n))
       [left right] (split-at at coll)]
    (concat right left)))
```

こんなやりかたを考えてみましたが、ごちゃごちゃして気持ち悪いですよね。
何かシンプルな方法はないでしょうか？

```
(defmulti vomit (fn [coll]
                  (if (list? coll) :list (if (vector? coll) :vector))) :default nil)
(defmethod vomit :list [coll] (partial apply list))
(defmethod vomit :vector [coll] (partial into (empty coll)))
(defmethod vomit nil [coll] identity)

(defn rotate [n coll]
  (let [at (if (neg? n) (Math/abs n) (- (count coll) n))
        [left right] (split-at at coll)]
    ((vomit coll) (concat right left))))
```

Comment: 質問冒頭に但し書きを追記しました。

Comment: 例にはありませんが、マップやセットに関しても必要でしょうか？マップは順序を作成時に保証する方法はありますが、変更を行うと保証がされません。

Comment: マップやセットに関しては、sorted-mapでもsorted-setでも不要です。これらをrotateさせることは、恐らく無いというか無意味だと思います。Stringはあり得るでしょうが。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

以下の様な書き方はいかがでしょうか。

```
(defn lisptype [x]
  (cond
    (list? x) list
    (vector? x) vector
    (map? x) hash-map
    (string? x) (fn [& x] (clojure.string/join x))
    true list))

(defn rotate [n coll]
  (let [at (if (neg? n) (Math/abs n) (- (count coll) n))
       [left right] (split-at at coll)]
  (apply (lisptype coll) (concat right left))))
```

※ map を渡すと妙な感じになりますが…

clojure の `type function` が Java の型ではなくて clojure 本来の型(list や vector)を返してくれればもう少し簡潔に書くことができるのですが…。

```
(apply (type coll) (concat right left))
```

追記:

rizaudo さんの回答を参考にさせていただいて、lisptype function を書き換えました。map に関しては array-map のみの対応で、set に関しては [Are there sets that keep the insertion order?](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clojure/vYND1CtKf2M) に記載されている order-preserving-set function を拝借しました(少し長いのでここには載せていません)。

```
(defn lisptype [x]
  (cond
    (list? x) list
    (vector? x) vector
    (set? x) order-preserving-set
    (map? x) (fn [& x] (apply array-map (flatten x)))
    (string? x) (fn [& x] (clojure.string/join x))
    :else list))
```

言わずもがなですが、rotate function に渡す set 型データは order-preserving-set function を使って作成する必要があります。

Comment: そうか、そうですね。単に最後にapplyすれば順序性を損なうことはないということですね。

Comment: おお、そこまでやりますかぁ。order-preserving-set。思わぬ方向ですが、芋づる式に勉強になります。ベクタでインデックスを保持、要素をキーにインデックスを管理。これらの操作を必要なインタフェース上で実装と。clojure.lang.Ixxを知ることで、こんなことができるんですね。

Answer (score 1):

Clojure標準には、コレクションにジェネリックに適用できる関数がそれほど多くないため、コレクションがシーカブルであることを利用してシーケンス関数を使うケースが多いですね。
その場合、結果として得られる値がシーケンスになってしまうため、入力のコレクション型を保存したい場合には不便です。

`empty`関数を使うと、引数に与えたコレクションと同じ型の空のコレクションが得られるので、型を保存したい場合にはこれと`conj`や`into`を組み合わせて使うのが比較的便利な方法です。

```
(defn rotate [n coll]
  (let [at (if (neg? n) (Math/abs n) (- (count coll) n))
        [left right] (split-at at coll)]
    (-> (empty coll) (into right) (into left))))
```

Comment: 以前に別の方が同じ方法を提案されたのですが、into を使いますと順序性が保証されません。例えば「(rotate 2 '(1 x y 2 z 3)) => (2 y x 1 3 z)」となってしまいます。正しくは「(z 3 1 x y 2)」となる必要があり、そのため apply function を使った次第です。

Comment: あーなるほど、完全に読み誤っていました。すみません。ユーザ定義型を含めたあらゆるコレクション型に対して、順序を保存しながら要素を追加する一般的な方法がないので、綺麗には定義できなさそうですね。

質問で期待されているものからは外れますが、rotateは一旦シーケンスを返す関数として定義しておき、どの型へ変換するかをユーザに指定させるようにするのが、より汎用的でClojureの他のAPIとも整合する方法かと思います。

Comment: それはもっともですけど。呼び出し側であれこれやるのもなー。
ですけど、では、こういう感じですかね。

```
(defn rotate [n coll & {:keys [constructor] :or {constructor list}}]
  (let [at (if (neg? n) (Math/abs n) (- (count coll) n))
       [left right] (split-at at coll)]
  (apply constructor (concat right left))))
```